# Machine Learning for Pressure Sensor via Accord.Net

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, accord.net

Our system has 4 pressure sensors and they give us data every 10 seconds and we use it to calculate average pressure in the system.

So basically we have table like

Timestamp - Value of Pressure

We need to predict  N possible values for at least 1 minute ahead based on this dataset.

I assume that https://github.com/accord-net is good to use for this objective.

Please, help to choose correct machine learning method to predict values using accord.net. And which samples here http://accord-framework.net/samples.html are best fitting to the task?

Thanks!